# $y$ is more than $\frac{2}{3}$, given ($\int_0^1f(x)[f(x)-y]\,\mathrm dx=0$)?

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

> $x\in [0,1]$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$,
>
> $f$ is increasing and weakly concave
>
> $$\int_0^1f(x)[f(x)-y]\,\mathrm dx=0$$
>
> We want to show that $y\geq\dfrac{2}{3}.$

My (complicated) approach is to consider the limiting case first: $f(x)$ is linear

Then the integral becomes $\dfrac{1}{3}1^3-\dfrac{1}{2}1^2\cdot y'=0$

We have $y'=2/3$.

Then we may prove that $y\,(f \text{ is concave})>y'\,(f \text{ is linear})$.

Does this approach works? Do you have smarter ideas?

Solve for $y$:

$$y=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1f^2\,\mathrm dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^1f\,\mathrm dx}$$

Let $g(x)=x$ be the linear function that I used above.

It seems like if $f$ is concave, then $f(x)\geq g(x)$, and

$f^2/f\geq g^2/g$ for any $x$.

Can we conclude that $\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1f^2\,\mathrm dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^1f\,\mathrm dx}\geq\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1g^2\,\mathrm dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^1g\,\mathrm dx}$ ?

---

Title edited. Thanks for comments! It is derived from an old practice contest question.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title that will help others find this problem and its solution.

Comment: We may get the explicit expression of $y = \cdots$?

Comment: @RiverLi How to?

Comment: Is it $y = \frac{\int_0^1 f^2 dx}{\int_0^1 f dx}$?

Comment: @RiverLi Then can we use some named inequality to get a solution?

Comment: I do not have a solution. Is the problem from competition? If so, maybe there is clever solution.

Comment: @RiverLi I updated the "answer" but I am not sure if it is right.